# Abstract functions and variable arguments list

Tags: c++, function, abstract, variadic-functions

I have an abstract class an I like to know if it's possible to define an abstract function with variable arguments list?

Give me an example if it's possible.

Comment: Please add a simple pseudo code example of what you would like to do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in principle.
An example follows below.
You can see the output [here](http://ideone.com/mjVs4).

Also read about variable arguments list  [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson17.html)  and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4181/Variable-Argument-Functions)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

using namespace std;


class AbstractClass{

public:

  virtual double average(int num, ... ) = 0;


};


class ConcreteClass : public AbstractClass{
public:

   virtual double average(int num, ... ) 
   {
      va_list arguments;                     // A place to store the list of arguments
      double sum = 0;

      va_start ( arguments, num );           // Initializing arguments to store all values after num
      for ( int x = 0; x < num; x++ )        // Loop until all numbers are added
        sum += va_arg ( arguments, double ); // Adds the next value in argument list to sum.
      va_end ( arguments );                  // Cleans up the list

      return sum / num;                      // Returns the average
  }



};



int main()
{
    AbstractClass* interface = new ConcreteClass();
    cout << interface->average( 3 , 20 ,30 , 40 );

    return 0;
}
```