# How can I write a Print method for variable arguments without templates?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

```
int temp=10;
string tempStr="hello";
LOG("test num:", temp, ", str:", tempStr);

#define LOG(...) Logger::getInstance().Print(__VA_ARGS__)
```

I already know how I make Print using template.
But I wonder that can I make Print without template?
Is it impossible?
Beacuse I want to make Print method from virtual function.

```
class Logger : public ILogger
{
public:
virtual void Print(...) override
{
// what should I do in here?
}
}

    class ILogger
    {
    public:
    virtual void Print(...) =0;
    }
```

Comment: Without any type information, how will you know whether the bit pattern 0x900abc is a pointer to a string or a number?

Comment: I am not sure my question is reasonable.

Comment: @sensolama I wouldn’t say it’s unreasonable but the answer is, you can’t. However, there’s nothing preventing you from using a function template: Write your `ILogger` base class so that it provides a `Print` function template which is non-virtual, and then have a virtual `PrintImpl` function that you dispatch to internally. You will then however need to dispatch in such a way as to preserve the type information.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your comment. My purpose is to use strategy pattern.

Comment: I believe the best option might be to split your problem. E.g. the base class `ILogger` provides a variadic template function to format the arguments into one buffer (e.g. a `std::string`). Then it may call a `virtual` member function for output of this buffer (which has to be overloaded in `Logger`). Concerning the variadic template function: You could use something already existing (e.g. `std::ostringstream`) so that you have lesser effort in your own code.

Comment: Perhaps interesting, the 2nd part of [SO: Specializing macro with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61114589/7478597) (Please, ignore the misleading title.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Abstract functions and variable arguments list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376872/abstract-functions-and-variable-arguments-list)

Comment: Scheff// Thanks. But it still not  available for me. Because my purpose is use stratege pattern. It means Print method can be modified   in inherited method.

Comment: S.M// yes. It is almost same. But the answer is only meet integer list.

Comment: S.M// if there are other good solution, I will refer to your advice (implement template method in ILogger then use output string in virtual function.) But I am not sure it is best way. Anyway thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 99% case is a reasonable number of parameters (10 or less), then having a separate LOG macro postfixed with a parameter count seems reasonable. Then any parameter that can be pushed via a a stream operator into the `stringstream` class will work.

Something like the following for supporting 1-4 parameters. Extending to 5 or more parameters is to just keep adding new macros.

```
void LogIt(const std::string& str)
{
    Logger::getInstance().Print(str.c_str());
}

#define LOG1(a) \
{ \
    std::ostringstream ss; \
    ss << a; \
    LogIt(ss.str()); \
}

#define LOG2(a, b) \
{ \
    std::ostringstream ss; \
    ss << a; \
    ss << b; \
    LogIt(ss.str()); \
}

#define LOG3(a, b, c) \
{ \
    std::ostringstream ss; \
    ss << a; \
    ss << b; \
    ss << c; \
    LogIt(ss.str()); \
}

#define LOG4(a, b, c, d) \
{ \
    std::ostringstream ss; \
    ss << a; \
    ss << b; \
    ss << c; \
    ss << d; \
    LogIt(ss.str()); \
}

int main()
{
    int temp = 10;
    std::string tempStr = "hello";
    LOG4("test num:", temp, ", str:", tempStr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think your answer is not good for me. Anyway thanks your opinion.